# How to remove the underline in a SSRS Link?

Tags: reporting-services

If I add an action in SSRS, I get a underline in reports.

[image]

Is it possible to remove it?

Answer (score 0):

SSRS does not automatically underline a link.

In reviewing the [TutorialGateway - Go To URL](https://www.tutorialgateway.org/go-to-url-action-in-ssrs/) page you were looking at, it seems that they didn't mention changing the *Font Effect* to Underline.

[image]

To toggle a Font's Underline effect, you can user {CTRL}+{U} or click on the underlined **U** in the font menu items.

[image]